# Fastest way to page / batch data from Oracle?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, performance, jdbc

Using a Java 8 jdbc preparedStatement and Oracle XE database, I'm looking for SQL to query pages of data from a table with many records.

Currently we are fetching 1000 records at a time using the following SQL statement...

```
select col1, col2, col3
from (select col1, col2, col3, rownum as ROW_NUM 
from some_table order by a_unique_key)
where row_num between 1 and 1000;
```

If anyone knows a better way to page this data please let me know.

Comment: The query you mentioned may not return the rows ordered by a_unique_key - rownum is assigned before ordering, something may change

Comment: select col1, col2, col3 from (select col1, col2, col3 from some_table order by a_unique_key) where rownum <= 1000;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how rownum will help you..
Try using bulk SQL with limit of 1000 records. So that in each pass you get 1000 records.